# Is eternity the same as infinite time or is eternity beyond time?

Tags: time, eternity

How can time not exist before creation? For God to exist for infinite time before creation, there had to have been some kind of time or time-like object causing -infinity to turn into the time of creation. Wouldn't God have created time before time so there was still time before creation but it may have had different properties?

Because eternity into the future is always described as infinite time in the future, but infinite time into the future can't actually happen technically and only approaching the infinite future can happen but never reaching it. So kind of like on a coordinate plane for e<sup>-x</sup>, where the coordinate plane tries to approach zero but it never actually is able to reach zero unless a value of infinity is placed in the value of x, which can't be shown on a coordinate plane. So is it kind of like the graph that I described in that eternity can never be reached and it doesn't exist at least in the future side, and eternity in the past does exist and has to exist? So does ever-increasing finite time give the illusion of eternity?

Comment: "For God to exist for infinite time before creation" Strictly speaking, Christians wouldn't say this is true. Time is part of the created universe. God's eternal existence is not within time, but we can only understand it *analogously* as being like infinite time.

Comment: But the thing before time is just not called time and called something else but it does the same thing as time then?So that still doesn't get around how an infinite amount of "something-like time" can pass unless if that "something like time" is a type of time that happens instantaneously kind of like teleportation but in time. So is this how you would view "time-like object before time"

Comment: Time is part of the universe, so there's not really anything "before" it in God's own existence.

Comment: What about space?Wouldn't God also have to be somewhere because he was everywhere and "where" doesn't make sense without space. So was there like a 4 dimensional space before creation but we don't call it space because it is called "hyperspace" but God reduced its dimensions to 3, because God has infinite dimensions?Is this true?

Comment: "So was there like a 4 dimensional space before creation" No. Before creation there was only God. Don't mistake descriptions of God's interactions within the created universe as descriptions of God's own intrinsic existence.

Comment: Eternity is not a long period of time nor is it 'infinite time' (a contradiction in terms), Eternity is a state _other than_ time. Likewise with dimension.

Comment: But is it actually possible to reach the edge of eternity, or is it just the finite time always forced to get bigger and bigger without end. So 10 years is forced to become 10^1000 years and then 10^1000 becomes 10^1000000, etc. So kind of like y=3x^2 where y=time, and x=time if there was no acceleration of time. So does y act like eternity. Is accelerated time the same eternal time?

Comment: Is this similar to the reason why acceleration results in Unruh Radiation, because according to the space-time, photons can't catch up to the accelerated observer from behind, so the space behind the accelerated object acts like a black hole and starts to radiate particles.

Answer (score -1):

**Eternal life** is simply defined as **life unending**. It is also referred to as **everlasting life**. The word is mentioned in the Bible several times especially in God's promise to the **elect**, anything that does not end is considered **infinite** just like **natural numbers**. I do not know if the dimension of time we are aware of now is the same time dimension that will be in existence after the resurrection but the life of the saints will be perpetuated by the **tree of life** and **the streams of eternal life flowing out of God's throne**

The saints have to technically drink and eat from these two to continue sharing in God's gift of everlasting life.

Comment: But your definition of eternity sounds like a type of function like y=10^x where there is acceleration of the numbers but no matter how big the base is, or how big x is, it will never actually reach infinity(eternity) because infinity is technically a concept and not a number. The only way y=infinity is if x=infinity, and the only way for y=0, is if x=-infinity, but assuming x is some function that is increasing by 1 second every second or even is a function where x=3z^2, where there is acceleration in how fast time flows, y can't be infinity. So is it true that eternal future isn't real.